# How can I move node's text content to attributes area using XSL?

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

I'm reading a XML file with the next structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DATA>
  <ROWS>
    <ROW ImString="string!" ImSmallint="5">
      <NestedROW>
        <ROW ImInteger="1" ImString="sub record 1"/>
        <ROW ImInteger="2" ImString="sub record 2"/>
      </NestedROW>
      ImShortint="1" ImSingle="6"
    </ROW>
    <ROW ImString="Soy string!" ImSmallint="5">
      <NestedROW>
        <ROW ImInteger="1" ImString="Hi World!"/>
        <ROW ImInteger="2" ImString="Bye World!"/>
      </NestedROW>
      ImShortint="3" ImSingle="5"
    </ROW>
  </ROWS>
</DATA>
```

as you can see, the node ROW has text content [ImShortint="3" ImSingle="5"], it should be after the ImSmallint attribute as shown in the expected result.

I tried with some XSL to merge or parse text() to generate and append attribute/value with no results, actually i have this incomplete XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[text()]">
    <xsl:variable name="text">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <!--
     Parse or merge text() here after last attribute
     -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I achieve the next XML output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DATA>
  <ROWS>
    <ROW ImString="string!" ImSmallint="5" ImShortint="1" ImSingle="6">
      <NestedROW>
        <ROW ImInteger="1" ImString="sub record 1"/>
        <ROW ImInteger="2" ImString="sub record 2"/>
      </NestedROW>
    </ROW>
    <ROW ImString="Soy string!" ImSmallint="5" ImShortint="3" ImSingle="5">
      <NestedROW>
        <ROW ImInteger="1" ImString="Hi World!"/>
        <ROW ImInteger="2" ImString="Bye World!"/>
      </NestedROW>
    </ROW>
  </ROWS>
</DATA>
```

**Edit:**
The XML can contain any number of attributes and the attribute names are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ROW[ parent::ROWS]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="ImShortint">
                <xsl:value-of select=" substring-before(substring-after(.,'&quot;'),'&quot; ')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ImSingle">
                <xsl:value-of select=" substring-before(substring-after(.,' ImSingle=&quot;'),'&quot;')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="NestedROW"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
check it.
```

Comment: You've interpreted the question as meaning that the input always contains two attributes named ImShortInt and ImSingle in that order. My interpretation was that it might contain any attributes, with unknown names. You might well be right, who knows, but it just shows how difficult it is to write a good requirements statement.

Comment: Incidentally, in XSLT 2.0 you can write `<xsl:attribute name="x" select="expr"/>` - the xsl:value-of instruction is redundant.

Comment: Michael Kay you are right, the XML can contain any number of attributes and the names are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROW">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="text2attributes">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(text())"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="text2attributes">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:attribute name="{substring-before($token, '=&quot;')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($token, '=&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="text2attributes">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

A better solution might be to fix the XML source, so that it doesn't output attributes as text.